# Bratamanda rules

Tags: yajur-veda, sama-veda

On Thursday I had this Bratamanda ceremony which is practiced in Nepal and maybe also in India but what I wanted to know is more of my freedom after I did that ceremony. When it was happening the respected priest was saying something in Sanskrit and said something about Brahmacharia and then later in I had to cross my hand, then I had to put the hands in the ground, and then I to say something. The priest made me say most of the things in Nepali which I do understand but he also made me say some things in Sanskrit which I don’t remember what he said. Does this mean that after bratamanda now I can’t do any sexual activities? They also made me wear a janai(I think it’s called upanayana in India) and I also had to get my head shaved for the ceremony. Would it be fine if I have a right to perform any sexual activities even after that(I also don’t mean this in any form of disrespected and if I disrespected the please forgive me) Thank you